# how to extract a particular substring from a string in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe "data" which as a column called "Description" which as a text " the IN678I78 is delivered" every row as some code starts with 'IN' 
now i need to pull that IN------ separately into new column 
please do help 
thanks

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), provide [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Comment: regular expressions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When asking a question, always put a sample of your dataframe for us to vizualize your problem and try some solutions.
IIUC you can use an apply on your `Description` column and regular expressions manipulation to extract your desired feature. You can try the following:

```
def extr(x):
    lis = x.split(' ')
    for string in lis:
        if string[:2] == 'IN':
            return string

data['New col'] = data.Description.apply(extr)
```